# How do I run "windows features" through Python?

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I'm trying to run `tftp` from a python script. I enabled it as a Windows 10 feature (http://www.trishtech.com/2014/10/enable-tftp-telnet-in-windows-10/) so I am able to run it via the command line. But when I try to run it through python I get errors. I tried 3 methods of calling it: os.system, subprocess.call, subprocess.Popen, and as a 'control' used those subprocesses to call 'dir' successfully. I also tried calling tftp from the full path. Code and output pasted below. I added delays and some printing to help parsing.

My guess is that when using those methods, the additional "windows features" that I enabled are not part of the environment that Python sees. But I'm not sure how to specify the environment to include the feature!

```
call("dir", shell = True)
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
call("tftp", shell = True)
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
call("C:\Windows\System32\\tftp.exe", shell = True)
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
Popen("dir", shell = True)
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
Popen("tftp", shell = True)
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
Popen("C:\Windows\System32\\tftp.exe", shell = True)
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
os.system("dir")
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
os.system("tftp")
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
os.system("C:\Windows\System32\\tftp.exe")
print "*******************************************"
time.sleep(1)
```

And the output I get is:

```
Directory of C:\[REDACTED]

07/26/2016  11:05 AM    <DIR>          .
07/26/2016  11:05 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/26/2016  11:05 AM             1,724 [REDACTED].py
07/26/2016  11:05 AM             1,828 [REDACTED].pyc
07/23/2016  05:36 PM             1,933 prep_for_bootload.py
07/26/2016  07:52 AM                13 s.bat
07/26/2016  11:19 AM             1,449 scrap.py
07/26/2016  10:38 AM               672 test_script.py
07/26/2016  10:39 AM                90 upload_script.bat
               7 File(s)          7,709 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  222,286,884,864 bytes free
*******************************************
'tftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
*******************************************
'C:\Windows\System32\tftp.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
*******************************************
*******************************************
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2AC7-8D0E

 Directory of C:\Users\[REDACTED]

07/26/2016  11:05 AM    <DIR>          .
07/26/2016  11:05 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/26/2016  11:05 AM             1,724 [REDACTED]
07/26/2016  11:05 AM             1,828 [REDACTED]
07/23/2016  05:36 PM             1,933 prep_for_bootload.py
07/26/2016  07:52 AM                13 s.bat
07/26/2016  11:19 AM             1,449 scrap.py
07/26/2016  10:38 AM               672 test_script.py
07/26/2016  10:39 AM                90 upload_script.bat
               7 File(s)          7,709 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  222,286,884,864 bytes free
*******************************************
'tftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
*******************************************
'C:\Windows\System32\tftp.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2AC7-8D0E

 Directory of C:\Users\[REDACTED]

07/26/2016  11:05 AM    <DIR>          .
07/26/2016  11:05 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/26/2016  11:05 AM             1,724 [REDACTED]
07/26/2016  11:05 AM             1,828 [REDACTED]
07/23/2016  05:36 PM             1,933 prep_for_bootload.py
07/26/2016  07:52 AM                13 s.bat
07/26/2016  11:19 AM             1,449 scrap.py
07/26/2016  10:38 AM               672 test_script.py
07/26/2016  10:39 AM                90 upload_script.bat
               7 File(s)          7,709 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  222,286,884,864 bytes free
*******************************************
'tftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
*******************************************
'C:\Windows\System32\tftp.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
*******************************************
```

Comment: Have you tried locating where `tftp` command is, and just manually calling it from it's full location? ie, if it's installed to `c:\windows\tftp.exe`, call it from python with it's full path.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well - adding this to my OP

Comment: `"\t"` is a tab character, not a backslash followed by a "t".

Comment: It's good practice to use native implementations rather than forking out. It'll give better integration and better error handling. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tftpy

Comment: Please provide the exact code you're using. See [mcve]

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I have been trying to implement tftpy but having lots of issues and hoping for this workaround. Based on your comment, I have edited and provided my original code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the \t was an example path file, not the actual one. I have edited to include my actual code instead, along with output.

Comment: There's no need to use `shell=True` just to run an executable. It doesn't solve the problem with running tftp.exe, which is only distributed as a 64-bit executable in the native "System32" directory. If your Python is 32-bit, then "System32" gets redirected to "SysWOW64" and the native directory is available as "SysNative". To work in either case, use `system32 = 'SysNative' if platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit' else 'System32'`. Then create the fully qualified path as `tftp_path = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], system32, 'TFTP.EXE')`.

Answer (score 0):

See response from: @eryksun for the correct answer. Quoted here:

"To work in either case, use system32 = 'SysNative' if platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit' else 'System32'. Then create the fully qualified path as tftp_path = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], system32, 'TFTP.EXE')"

Comment: You can write an answer in your own words. This is a very common problem, but I don't think it's easy to search for answers because there's a fundamental disconnect between what you're trying to do -- execute a program -- and the underlying problem -- virtualization of the filesystem under WOW64.